# Can assembler use movw instruction on 1byte register?

Tags: assembly, x86, elf, disassembly, mov

There are 4 types of `mov` instruction : `movb`, `movw`, `movl`.
Suffix `b`,`w`,`l` means size of source register.

However, while assembling, I caught problem on those suffix.
See below example.

```
 .global main
 main:
  movb %ss, (%ecx) # ==> assemble (X)
  movw %ss, (%ecx) # ==> assemble (O)
```

Even though source register `%ss` is 1byte size,

1byte instruction  `movb %ss, (%ecx)` assemble ***failed***,
2byte instruction `movw %ss, (%ecx)` assemble ***succeded***.

Why this happens?
Is it just linux `as` bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ss register is 16 bits (2 bytes) long, so movw is indeed correct while `movb` is rightfully rejected.

In general, unless no register operand is present, you can simply leave out the size suffix and let the assembler infer it.  The assembler typically does a very good job with that.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that `%ss` is 1byte sized register... 
Thank you very much!